# How to build a nanocluster?

Tags: software, one-topic-per-answer, software-recommendations, symmetry, nanostructures

What are the software tools (if possible open source) or methods we can use for constructing a nanocluster, most preferably with high symmetry such as icosahedron, octahedron, cuboctahedron etc. ?

Answer (score 9):

A possible tool is the ASE python package (open-source):

https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/cluster/cluster.html

Another tool is [materials studio software](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/biovia/products/molecular-modeling-simulation/biovia-materials-studio/). Unfortunately, it is not free.

Answer (score 8):

## Nanocut

From its [site](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/nanocut/src/master/):

> Nanocut is a program designed to cut out various objects from three
> dimensional crystal structures. It is aimed to be helpful when
> creating geometry input for atomistic simulations. Currently it can
> create following objects:
>
> - Spherical cluster
> - Polyhedral cluster
> - Cylindrical cluster
> - Spherical wire (1D periodic)
> - Polyhedral wire (1D periodic)
> - Plain slab (2D periodic)
> - Supercells (3D periodic)

Answer (score 4):

## Atomsk

I like to use [Atomsk](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr) to build clusters.

> Atomsk is a free, Open Source command-line program dedicated to the creation, manipulation, and conversion of data files for atomic-scale simulations. It supports the file formats used by many programs.
>
> Atomsk proposes options for applying elementary transformations: duplicate, rotate, deform, insert dislocations, merge several systems, create bicrystals and polycrystals, etc. These elementary tools can be combined to construct and shape a wide variety of atomic systems. To learn more, you are invited to read [the documentation](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/doc.php), and to follow [the tutorials](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/tutorials.php).

"Atomsk: A tool for manipulating and converting atomic data files"
Pierre Hirel, Comput. Phys. Comm. 197 (2015) 212-219
[doi:10.1016/j.cpc.2015.07.012](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465515002817)